# How to remove the gap in the ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is my data frame

```
Days,Observed,Simulated
0,0,424.8933328
1,1070,1116.781453
2,2360,2278.166227
3,3882,3854.781359
4,5712,5682.090936
5,7508,7565.230044
6,9126,9343.991798
7,10600,10919.17995
8,11893,12249.07067
9,13047,13332.93044
10,14022,14193.53941
11,14852,14863.84784
12,15480,15378.56415
13,16042,15769.6773
14,16362,16064.57556
15,16582,16285.66038
16,16766,16450.70955
17,16854,16573.54275
18,16854,16664.74816
```

And this is my code, hope I didn't miss out some information

```
dt <- read.csv('data.csv')
days <- dt$Days
Observed <- dt$Observed
Simulated <- dt$Simulated

require(ggplot2)
R <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = days))+geom_line(y=Simulated, color="red", size=0.5)+
  geom_point(y=Observed, color="midnightblue", size=1.75)
a <- geom_line(aes(y = Simulated, col='Simulated'))
n <- geom_point(aes(y = Observed, fill = "Observed"), col='blue')
c <- ggtitle("2.5kg of Placenta & 0.5kg of seed") 
h <- labs(x = 'Time(Days)', y = "Cumulative Biogas Yield(ml)", 
          colour = NULL, fill = "Legend")
o <- theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.1))+
  theme( plot.title = element_text(colour = "midnightblue"),
         axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
         axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
         legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
         legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12.5),
         axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
         axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14))
d <- scale_color_manual(values = 'red')
s <- scale_fill_manual(values = 'midnightblue')
Myplot <- R+a+n+c+h+o+d+s
Myplot
```

The result I get have a big gap between the variables and needs to be removed

[image: The legend have a big gap between the Variables]

What I want is as follows:

[image: No gap between the variables]

I have edited the graph on the painter to get what i want but its tiresome work I would like to have the code that can easy the process for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing between the two legends using a combination of two theme elements: `legend.spacing` and `legend.margin`.  I played around a bit with these and this combination seems to work well:

```
Myplot + theme(
    legend.spacing = unit(0,'pt'),
    legend.margin = margin(t=0,b=0,unit='pt')
  )
```

[image]
*side note*
Also, just wanted to note that when you want to squish together two legends, but have one title, it is better to do it like you have (where one of the legend titles is set to `NULL` rather than an empty character `""`.  `NULL` effectively removes the legend title as an element and makes spacing easier, whereas `""` still carries the spacing of the title, even if nothing is represented.  If you replace `NULL` with `""` in your code, you'll see this... so good job with that :).

Comment: A few seconds apart. I think your answer deserved the tick though for helpful side note. +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for `theme(legend.margin)`?

```r
Myplot + theme(legend.margin = margin(0, 0, -10, 0))
```

[image]